# Выбор sql запроса через ajax, php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Помогите, как можно дописать код...
Вводишь Логин,Пароль, выбираешь через radio кнопку (обработка ajax) перебрасывало после этого на страницу либо doc.php, либо pacient.php

index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<div class="loginform-in">
<h1>User Login</h1>
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<fieldset>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Username </label>
            <input type="text" size="30"  name="name" id="name">
            <label for="name">Password</label>
            <input type="text" size="30"  name="word" id="word">

            <input type="radio" id="pac" name="sick" value="pac">Я доктор
            <input type="radio" id="doc" name="sick" value="doc">Я пациент
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="login" name="loginin" value="Войти" class="loginbutton">
         </form>    
</fieldset>
</div>
```

login.js (ajax обработчик)

```
/*------------ДОКТОР------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
     $("#login").click(function() { 
          username=$("#name").val();
          password=$("#word").val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: "username="+username+"&pass="+password,
            success: function(html) { 
            if(html=='true') {
                $('#add_err').html('Вы успешно вошли в аккаунт!');
                setTimeout("window.location='ok.php';",1000);
            }
            else {
                $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                $("#add_err").html("<img style='width:32;' src='alert.png'>Неверный Логин или Пароль!");
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function() {
                $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                $("#add_err").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif'>Загрузка...")
           }
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

login.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['sick']) == 'doc') {
$uName = $_POST['username'];
$pWord = $_POST['pass'];
$qry = "SELECT userid, username FROM usermetaDOCTOR WHERE username='".$uName."' AND pass='".$pWord."'  ";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if($num_row == 1) {
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['oId'] = $row['orgid'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
else {
$uName = $_POST['username'];
$pWord = $_POST['pass'];
$qry = "SELECT userid, username FROM usermetaPACIENT WHERE username='".$uName."' AND pass='".$pWord."'  ";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($res);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if($num_row == 1) {
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['oId'] = $row['orgid'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Так а в чем проблема?

Comment: Не проверяет чекнута ли radio кнопка

Comment: Что именно? `PHP` код или `JS`?

Comment: JS, всё ли там правильно?

Comment: А вы на `JS` вообще не отправляете значение `radio` кнопки.